# WCF service hosted in Windows service

Tags: wcf, windows-services

I have a WCF service hosted in a Windows service. When user modifies the WCF service configuration,he needs to restart the service.

I wanted to know if restarting the windows service is better by using

```
serviceController.stop() 
servicecontroller.start()
```

or by creating a new instance of the WCF client every time he wants to restart it. No information will be lost if created a new instance of the WCF client.

Comment: Creating a new client isn't really going to restart the service - so I think that's really not an option for you...

Comment: ya but the configuration parameters will be reset right? That is all I want.Is it a good idea to create a new client?

Comment: Please explain the part of your question that comes after "or by creating ..."

Comment: nowaq: I mean I will have added a service reference of WCF service in the client right.Using that I will create a new client every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your service container which is inherited from  `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase`

you should start your service inside method

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
  servicecontroller.start()
}
```

and stop your services inside method

```
protected override void OnStop()
{
    //here clean up code or any tear-down necessary to stop your service.
  serviceController.stop() 
 }
```

so these methods are called automatically when you start/stop windows service from services pallet.

As others said there is no effect of `creating a new instance of the WCF client every time` on your service